# Cannot connect to IIS using own IP

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am hosting an asp.net MVC 3 application on my local IIS 7.5 server. People can connect using my IP and the port I set. I can connect by typing localhost:port in a browser. If I type the IP:port however, the browser says it cannot connect.

Using wamp and other hosting programs (and even IIS at one point if memory serves), I could always connect using my own IP.

How can I set IIS to let me connect using my own IP? Or is the problem somewhere else?

My firewall is disabled, the port is forwarded and other people can connect just fine (people outside my LAN) and I have tried 3 browsers.

Comment: Why are you using a port #? why not use the default port 80. You say people can connect but you can't? Why do you even want to connect using IP, better to connect via hostname. Is this inside a domain? You might review my blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/04/22/test-you-asp-net-mvc-or-webforms-application-on-iis-7-in-30-seconds.aspx

Comment: Can you telnet to 127.0.0.1 80?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot connect to your IIS using static IP, but, howerver you can by adding your Static IP as a lookup entry.

Please check this link:
[How to Edit Your Windows Hosts File](http://www.ehow.com/how_5225562_edit-windows-hosts-file.html)

The article explains how to resolve the IP to reach the IIS locally.